# Fetch all data with particular sheet names

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Can you please anyone tell me how to Excel all data with particular sheet names insert in MS-SQL table. I am using C# code with MVC 5, This is my code C# and MVC 5

```
                    string path1 = @"c:\users\vaio\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\test\Test2\Content\";

                    string fileFullPath = Path.GetFullPath(path1);
                    excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source=" + fileFullPath + ";Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\"";
                }

                DataSet data = new DataSet();

                foreach (var sheetName in GetExcelSheetNames(excelConnectionString))
                {
                    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
                    {
                        var dataTable = new DataTable(sheetName);
                        string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", sheetName);
                        con.Open();
                        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);
                        adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                        data.Tables.Add(dataTable);

                        using (TtestContext dc = new TtestContext())
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                            {
                                string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TtestContext"].ConnectionString;
                                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
                                string query2 = "Insert  into  ExcelTemps(Courier,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9,F10) Values('"
                                + dataTable.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString().Replace("'", "''") + "','"
                                + dataTable.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString().Replace("'", "''") + "','"
                                + dataTable.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString().Replace("'", "''") + "' ,'"
                                + dataTable.Tables[0].Rows[i][3].ToString().Replace("'", "''") + "','"
                                + dataTable.Tables[0].Rows[i][4].ToString().Replace("'", "''") + "','"
                                + dataTable.Tables[0].Rows[i][5].ToString().Replace("'", "''") + "','"
                                + dataTable.Tables[0].Rows[i][6].ToString().Replace("'", "''") + "','"
                                + dataTable.Tables[0].Rows[i][7].ToString().Replace("'", "''") + "','"
                               + dataTable.Tables[0].Rows[i][8].ToString().Replace("'", "''") + "','"
                               + dataTable.Tables[0].Rows[i][9].ToString().Replace("'", "''") + "','"
                                   + dataTable + "')";
                                con.Open();
                                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query2, con);
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                con.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return View();
    }

    static string[] GetExcelSheetNames(string connectionString)
    {
        OleDbConnection con = null;
        DataTable dt = null;
        con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        con.Open();
        dt = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

        if (dt == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        String[] excelSheetNames = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
        int i = 0;

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            excelSheetNames[i] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            i++;
        }
        return excelSheetNames;
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like you are well on your way.  What is wrong with your current code?

Comment: It is working but data duplicated(7 times, because sheet has 7 work sheet)

Comment: So is each sheet a duplicate of the other?

Comment: yes It is , For example one sheet has 10  data recode, (I have 7 sheets names excel file) data base usually insert 70 record, but my code insert 700 records.

Comment: Have you debugged and stepped through the code?

Comment: How many sheetnames does `GetExcelSheetNames` return?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: return 7 sheets name + some other name ''_xlnm#Print_Titles''
Annie2$
Enzo188$
Greg11$
Jennifer15$
Joana190$
Laurie196$
Mick145$

Comment: 'System.Data.DataTable' does not contain a definition for 'Tables' and no extension method 'Tables' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataTable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 

for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)